# Check if file exists that starts with given string

Tags: php, apache, file, exists

Given a name

```
$path = 'articles/001.html';
```

I can check if such a file exists like so:

```
if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
    // include it
} else {
    // redirect to articles index
}
```

However, I was thinking about modifying the URL of the article by adding the title of the article to it. So, if the user requests this URL:

```
"http://foo.com/articles/001"
```

I would like to transform the URL to this:

```
"http://foo.com/articles/001/the-title-of-the-article-here"
```

Now, this of course means that I have to store the title of that article (and all other articles) somewhere. The title is located in the `<h1>` element of the article, but I doubt that reading the article (file) on the server just to retrieve the title is a good idea.

So, I was thinking about putting the title in the file name like so:

```
"001-the-title-of-the-article-here.html"
```

Then I could just extract it from the file name and add it to the URL. However, I'm not sure how to check if such a file exists in the `articles` directory - all I got is the article ID (`001` in this case).

So, based on an ID, I would like to check if there exists an HTML page inside the `articles` directory that starts with that ID, and if yes, I would like to retrieve its file name.

Can this be done? Is this a good approach? Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`glob`](http://php.net/glob) can match files according to a pattern for you:

```
$files = glob('articles/001-*.html');
```

It gives you back an array of all matched files.

Comment: How would I concatenate the ID to the string? I'm getting the ID from `$_GET['id']`. This - `glob( 'articles/.$_GET['id'].-*.html' )` - throws an error.

Comment: You're just mixing up your quotes. `'articles/' . $_GET['id'] . '-*.html'`.

Comment: Ah this - `glob( 'articles/'.$_GET['id'].'-*.html' )`. Got it.